# log4net on Windows Forms doesn't write log file

Tags: c#, winforms, log4net

I'm developing a Windows Form app with .NET Framework 4.0 and log4net 1.2.13.

This is the first time I use log4net in a Windows Form application and it doesn't work. Maybe I forget a configuration step nut now, it doesn't work: **I can't find the log file**.

This is how I instance logger:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog _logger =
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MainForm));
```

And this is App.Config contents:

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <appender type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" name="AppLogErrorAppender">
    <file value="D:\\AppError.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
    <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
    <countDirection value="1" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <logger name="AppLog">
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="AppLogErrorAppender" />
  </logger>
  <root>
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="AppLogErrorAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I'm logging here:

```
public const string LogExceptionNameMessageFormatString = "EXCEPTION: {0} - Message: {1}";

private void LogError(string exceptionMessage, string exceptionName)
{
    _logger.ErrorFormat(LogExceptionNameMessageFormatString, exceptionName, exceptionMessage);
}
```

I have a breakpoint on it, and it stops.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "doesn't work" is very vague - what behaviour are you observing? Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, instead of just a snippet?

Comment: I have updated my question. The problem is that I can't find the log file.

Comment: Log files are generated when the application tries to log something (when you call _logger.Info etc) , not when the application starts. Are you logging anything? Have you initialized log4net with your configuration? Please post the relevant code

Comment: That doesn't look like a App.Config, it looks like a seperate log4net config file. You need to initialise log4net to read the config file: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Comment: @StuartGrassie This is part of my App.Config file. I haven't put all to don't put irrelevant data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Program.cs:

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    /* other stuff */
}
```

I will usually also Log something immediately in `void Main`, after configuration.

App.config:

You need to remember to put in the log4net config section as the first element of the `<configSections>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
        <configSections>
                <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
        </configSections>
        <startup>
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
        </startup>

        <log4net>
                <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
                        <file value="log.log"/>
                        <appendToFile value="true"/>
                        <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
                        <maxSizeRollBackups value="1"/>
                        <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
                        <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
                        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                                <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
                        </layout>
                </appender>

                <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
                        <immediateFlush value="true"/>
                        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                                <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %property{detailContext} %-5level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
                        </layout>
                </appender>

                <root>
                        <level value="ALL"/>
                        <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>
                        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
                </root>
        </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There was something wrong on log4net `AppLogErrorAppender` configuration.

Comment: About you words   [You need to remember to put in the log4net config section as the first element of the <configSections>:]   I don't think it is necessary to put the log4net config section as the first element of the <configSections>..

Answer (score 1):

You need to call:

```
  XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Before logging anything. This will init log4net and read the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to set up log4net in my application and get it to work. Here is what I learnt:

Reference the log4net in your code, create a log by calling GetLogger and write to the log using one of the logging method.

```
using log4net;
...
private static ILog Log;
...
Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Ref-A");
Log.Info("test-A");
Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
Log.Debug("test-B");

2018-05-29 21:32:58,574 [1] Ref-A - testA
2018-05-29 21:32:58,575 [1] MyMethod - testB
```

When calling GetLogger, you pass it a string that will prefix the log line, typically the current class and/or method.

In AssemblyInfo.cs you need to add one of the lines below. You can reference log4net.Config with a using clause or prefix the call to XmlConfigurator.

The first syntax, w/o specifying the name of the file will use the App.config. The second syntax I found mentioned in the documentation and some posts is for using a separate log4net.config file. Finally if using log4net in a dependent assembly, you need to specify the name of the config file which will be generated so that log4net looks there and not in the calling application App.config.

```
//use App.config
using log4net.Config;
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

//use log4net.config
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config",Watch = true)]

//use myLibrary.dll.config
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "myLibrary.dll.config",Watch = true)]
```

Here is the App.config I used. It works with scenario 1 and 3 above and an absolute file path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
      <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\temp\myLog.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Another couple of tips.

- When debugging, check the properties of the values returned by GetLogger - IsDebugEnabled, IsInfoEnabled, etc. - if they are all set to false, your log configuration is wrong and the log won't write anything.
- If you have multiple projects using log4net and one fails to create a log, then all the others will fail too. At least in my scenario where many dlls where calling the same base class and the base class was failing to create the first log. All the logs everywhere in the program where not working either.